# How do I fetch drag-drop title, start, end and resourceId altogether?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I'm attempting to successfully collect all of the event data from a drag-and-drop. I was partially successful in doing so by utilizing `eventReceive`. It managed to fetch the `title`, `start` and `end` but not the `resourceID`.

Apparently `eventReceive` (and subsequently 'Event Object') only permits for `title`, `start` and `end` but not `resourceID` which is what is causing the issue.

I noticed that however the section right above `drop:` is grabbing and console.logging the `resourceId` using `arg.resource.id`.

So the question I have is how I can possibly combine the two, and output all of `title`, `start`, `end` and `resourceID`. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
drop: function(arg) {
  console.log('drop date: ' + arg.dateStr)

  if (arg.resource) {
    console.log('drop resource: ' + arg.resource.id)
    const resourceID = arg.resource.id;
    console.log('TESTING: ' + resourceID);
  }

  if (document.getElementById('drop-remove').checked) {
    arg.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(arg.draggedEl);
  }
},

eventReceive: function(arg) { // called when a proper external event is dropped
  console.log('eventReceive', arg.event);
  const eventData = {
    title: arg.event.title,
    resourceId: arg.event.resourceId,
    start: arg.event.start,
    end: arg.event.end,
  };
  console.log(eventData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `drop` callback, the resource ID is part of the general drop info, since at that moment there isn't a calendar event yet. So there's no particularl the resource info would be accessible in a similar manner from an event object - the two things are unrelated.

Frustratingly though, the [event object documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) doesn't actually specify how to read the associated resource data from an event. It seems like the associated resources aren't intended to be a public property of an event, for some reason.

From examining the internals of `arg.event` when it's logged to the console, we can see that instead of a `resourceId` property, there's actually a `resourceIds` property within the `_def` property, which is an array of resource IDs - an event [can be associated with multiple resources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-and-events).

So you *could* access that property, but it's not really supposed to be public, so we shouldn't rely on it. Fortunately a quick look at the fullCalendar documentation shows that the event object has a handy [getResources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-getResources) method you can call.

So if in the `eventReceive` callback you write:

```
const eventData = {
  title: arg.event.title,
  resourceIds: arg.event.getResources().map(function(resource) { return resource.id }),
  start: arg.event.start,
  end: arg.event.end,
};
```

This will retrieve the array of resourceIds the event is assigned to. Of course in the context of having just dropped the event onto the calendar in a specific location, in practice this array will only ever contain one entry.

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGYQXLJ

Comment: It has certainly worked. Following on from this, as it returns an array what would be the way to extract specifically the Id from within it? The Event::getResources docs state that you can return the id through a const but how would that apply in this scenario? This is all in preparation for it to be sent off to a database.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean, I can't see a mention of a `const` in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-getResources ? But anyway `getResources` just returns an array. You can access its properties/indexes [just like any other JS array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays). So if you know there's only going to be one entry, you could get the specific ID by referencing index 0. e.g. `arg.event.getResources()[0]`, or longhand: `var resources = arg.event.getResources(); console.log(resources[0]);` or whatever.

Comment: Apologies I meant 'var resourceIds'. I have now given your referencing the index a go. This returned "ResourceAPI" which does seem to have the id within it. How can it be accessed? Picture linked: https://imgur.com/s4tLnYJ

Comment: Ah ok. It returns an array of Resource objects. The Id is just a property of the resource object (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-object) , so you can use `arg.event.getResources()[0].Id` (for example). Or alternatively if you want a pure list of all the Ids in a simple array, rather than objects, you can use the example from the documentation where it makes use of `.map()`

Comment: Solved the issue, thanks! For anyone looking for future reference its specifically >arg.event.getResources()[0].id

Comment: Apologies yes it's `id` rather than `Id`

Comment: I've amended the answer to return an array of IDs (via .map()) as per my description, rather than an array of resources.